# suppress Chrome default message onmouseover when Required Attribute is set

Tags: google-chrome, onmouseover, required

I am developing a form in html5, I have put the required attribute and customized the tool tip. When I press the submit button the customized tooltip appears however when I hover over the field I see default message "please fill out this field" in addition to custom tooltip post submission attempt or only default message pre submission. I like either to translate the default message or suppress it. The behavior is unique to chrome. Any help will be much appreciated.

I have tried using the setCustomValidity() onmouseover event but in vain

Regards

Yasir Munir

```
   <html>
<head>
    <script>
        function validator(input) {
             input.setCustomValidity('my custom message');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" required onmouseover="validator(this)" oninput="validator(this)" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Personally i will not recommend to use html5 for front-end validation because it's too basic; why don't you use a Javascript or Jquery solution which can be more practic and built in with automatic translation function?

Comment: @Evrad-c That could be a fall back the current implementation works nicely in firefox and if go for full JS based sln that will involve a lot of rework, before committing to that path I wish to be sure there is no other way